# Vertical CollectionView inside TableViewCell working not correctly - UIKit & Storyboard

Tags: swift, uikit, storyboard, tableview, collectionview

What I have:
Horizontal CollectionView inside TableViewCell working good, as expected
[image]

What I need:
Vertical CollectionView inside TableViewCell like on Android version app
[image]

What I tried:

In Storyboard:

1. Switch CollectionView flow to vertical
2. Set Estimated Size of CollectionViewCell to None
3. Disable scrolling
4. Set class DynamicHeightCollectionView to my CollectionView

```
class DynamicHeightCollectionView: UICollectionView {
  
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        if bounds.size != intrinsicContentSize {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    }
    
}
```

TableViewCell

```
class DayEmptySeatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelWeekday: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewEmptySeats: UICollectionView!
    
    var dayEmptySeat: DayEmptySeat? {
        didSet {
            setDayEmptySeat()
        }
    }
    
    var delegate: DayEmptySeatCellDelegate?
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        labelDate.text = ""
        labelWeekday.text = ""
        
        collectionViewEmptySeats.dataSource = self
        collectionViewEmptySeats.delegate = self
        collectionViewEmptySeats.register(UINib(nibName: "EmptySeatCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "EmptySeatCollectionViewCell")
        
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    func setDayEmptySeat() {
        guard let dayEmptySeat else { return }
        
        labelDate.text = dayEmptySeat.date
        labelWeekday.text = dayEmptySeat.weekDay
        
        collectionViewEmptySeats.reloadData()
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
           return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dayEmptySeat?.emptySeats.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionViewEmptySeats.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EmptySeatCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? EmptySeatCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        guard let dayEmptySeat else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        let emptySeat = dayEmptySeat.emptySeats[indexPath.row]
        cell.emptySeat = emptySeat
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

[image]

The strange behavior is that the next row of CollectionView is transferred incorrectly. By first call ViewController I receive this
[image]

Then close it, second call and I receive this
[image]

Sometimes 4th, 7th etc. calls has affect CollectionViews in another TableViewCells. Randomly.

Any thoughts can help. Thank you.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using a collection view for this... you're fighting against its default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UICollectionView` is designed to lay out its cells based on its frame, with auto-scrolling capability, optimized for memory usage by reusing cells and **not** creating cells that are not visible.

Trying to use "self-sizing" collection views is generally a losing battle, because that code is trying to *set the frame based on the cell layout*. When embedding them in a table view cell, you run into more problems because the collection view frame width won't be set until the table view sets the table view cell's frame.

To offer a different approach -- let's get rid of the table view and instead use a collection view with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`.

For the basics of a custom layout, we generate an array of cell frames, and then tell the collection view to populate those frames with cells as needed.

It appears that **your** layout will use fixed-size cell frames, which makes the process fairly straight-forward.

So, instead of this, with embedded collection views in cells in a table view:

[image]

We could do this, with a single collection view:

[image]

I had helped someone else with a similar-but-different layout task here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75902340/6257435 ... and made a few modifications.

We'll start with a data struct:

```
struct EmptySeatStruct {
    var date: Date = Date()
    var timeSlots: [Date] = []
}
```

The header view will look like this:

[image]

and with some colors so we can see the element framing:

[image]

Pretty basic class for `UICollectionReusableView`:

```
class TimeSlotsSectionHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {
    static let identifier: String = "TimeSlotsSectionHeaderView"
    
    let labelDate: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .bold)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    let labelWeekday: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .light)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        addSubview(labelDate)
        addSubview(labelWeekday)
        let g = self
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            labelDate.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            labelDate.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            labelDate.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            labelWeekday.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            labelWeekday.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            labelWeekday.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])
    }
    // for development, so we can see the framing
    var showHeaderFrame: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = showHeaderFrame ? .systemBlue : .clear
            labelDate.backgroundColor = showHeaderFrame ? .yellow : .clear
            labelWeekday.backgroundColor = showHeaderFrame ? .yellow : .clear
        }
    }
}
```

and a cell view:

[image] [image]

```
class TimeSlotsCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier: String = "TimeSlotsCell"
    
    public let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.textColor = .init(red: 0.0, green: 0.1, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .regular)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    private var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let thisLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        thisLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        thisLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        thisLayer.shadowOffset = .zero
        thisLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
        thisLayer.shadowRadius = 2
        thisLayer.shouldRasterize = true
        return thisLayer
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = contentView
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: 8.0, dy: 8.0), cornerRadius: 8.0).cgPath
        shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
    }

    // if we want to change the appearance when cell is selected
    //  for example, changing the background to cyan
    //override var isSelected: Bool {
    //  didSet {
    //      shadowLayer.fillColor = isSelected ? UIColor.cyan.cgColor : UIColor.white.cgColor
    //  }
    //}
    
    // for development, so we can see the framing
    var showCellFrame: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            contentView.layer.borderColor = showCellFrame ? UIColor.blue.cgColor : UIColor.clear.cgColor
            contentView.layer.borderWidth = showCellFrame ? 1 : 0
            theLabel.backgroundColor = showCellFrame ? .green : .clear
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the custom `UICollectionViewLayout` class:

```
protocol TimeSlotsGridLayoutDelegate: AnyObject {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForSectionHeaderAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, insetsForSectionHeaderAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    func itemSize(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> CGSize
    func itemSpacing(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> CGFloat
    func rowSpacing(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> CGFloat
}
// make custom delegate funcs optional
extension TimeSlotsGridLayoutDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForSectionHeaderAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, insetsForSectionHeaderAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return .zero
    }
    func itemSize(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> CGSize {
        return .init(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
    }
    func itemSpacing(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }
    func rowSpacing(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }
}

class TimeSlotsGridLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    
    weak var delegate: TimeSlotsGridLayoutDelegate?
    
    // some defaults
    private let defaultItemSize: CGSize = .init(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
    private let defaultItemSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0
    private let defaultRowSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0
    private let defaultHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    private let defaultHeaderInsets: UIEdgeInsets = .zero
    
    // internal properties
    private var headerCache: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
    private var itemCache: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
    
    private var nextY: CGFloat = 0.0
    private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }
    
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }
    
    override func prepare() {
        
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        
        let cellSize: CGSize = delegate?.itemSize(collectionView) ?? defaultItemSize
        let itemSpacing: CGFloat = delegate?.itemSpacing(collectionView) ?? defaultItemSpacing
        let rowSpacing: CGFloat = delegate?.rowSpacing(collectionView) ?? defaultRowSpacing

        let numCols: Int = Int(contentWidth / (cellSize.width + itemSpacing))
        
        var thisFrame: CGRect = .zero
        
        itemCache = []
        headerCache = []
        
        nextY = 0.0
        
        for section in 0..<collectionView.numberOfSections {
            
            let headerHeight = delegate?.collectionView(collectionView, heightForSectionHeaderAt: section) ?? defaultHeaderHeight
            let headerInsets = delegate?.collectionView(collectionView, insetsForSectionHeaderAt: section) ?? defaultHeaderInsets
            
            let attrHeader = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, with: IndexPath(row: 0, section: section))
            attrHeader.frame = CGRect(x: headerInsets.left, y: nextY + headerInsets.top, width: contentWidth - (headerInsets.left + headerInsets.right), height: headerHeight)
            nextY += headerHeight + headerInsets.top + headerInsets.bottom
            headerCache.append(attrHeader)
            
            let y: CGFloat = nextY
            
            var curCol: Int = 0
            var curRow: Int = 0
            
            let itemsInSection: Int = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
            let rowsInSection: Int = itemsInSection / numCols
            
            // we want to know how many cells will be in each "row" in the section
            //  so we can horizontally center the rows
            var rowItemCounts: [Int] = Array(repeating: numCols, count: rowsInSection)
            if itemsInSection % numCols != 0 {
                rowItemCounts.append(itemsInSection % numCols)
            }
            
            for item in 0..<itemsInSection {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                
                // if we're at the last column
                if curCol == numCols {
                    // increment the row
                    curRow += 1
                    // restart at column Zero
                    curCol = 0
                }
                
                // horizontal row centering
                let interItemSpace: CGFloat = CGFloat(rowItemCounts[curRow] - 1) * itemSpacing
                let cellsWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(rowItemCounts[curRow]) * cellSize.width
                let rowWidth: CGFloat = interItemSpace + cellsWidth
                let xOffset: CGFloat = (contentWidth - rowWidth) * 0.5
                
                let xPos: CGFloat = curCol == 0 ? 0.0 : CGFloat(curCol) * (cellSize.width + itemSpacing)
                let yPos: CGFloat = curRow == 0 ? 0.0 : CGFloat(curRow) * (cellSize.height + rowSpacing)
                
                thisFrame = .init(x: xPos + xOffset, y: y + yPos, width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)

                let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
                attributes.frame = thisFrame
                itemCache.append(attributes)
                
                // increment the column
                curCol += 1
                
            }
            
            // we need to account for sections with Zero items
            //  so don't update nextY if there were no items in this section
            if collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) > 0 {
                // next section starts after the bottom of
                //  primary Frame or the last secondary Frame
                //  whichever is greatest
                nextY = thisFrame.maxY
            }
            
        }
        
        contentHeight = nextY
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        
        var visibleLayoutAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
        
        for attributes in itemCache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        
        for attributes in headerCache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        super.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: elementKind, at: indexPath)
        return headerCache.count > indexPath.section ? headerCache[indexPath.section] : nil
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
        return itemCache.count > indexPath.row ? itemCache[indexPath.row] : nil
    }
    
}
```

and finally, the view controller:

```
class TimeSlotsViewController: UIViewController {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var myData: [EmptySeatStruct] = []
    
    // for development purposes
    var showCellFrame: Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        view.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.96, alpha: 1.0)
        let gl = TimeSlotsGridLayout()
        gl.delegate = self
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: gl)
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(TimeSlotsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: TimeSlotsCell.identifier)
        collectionView.register(TimeSlotsSectionHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: TimeSlotsSectionHeaderView.identifier)

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

        // let's create some sample data, starting on current date
        //  each day will have n number of half-hour "time slots"
        //  starting at 09:00

        let countOfTimeSlots: [Int] = [6, 3, 9, 7, 8, 11, 4, 5, 3, 1, 9, 13, 9, 10, 13, 5, 5, 10, 1, 13]
        
        // this date manipulation should never fail, but in general,
        //  we should safely unwrap optionals...
        
        guard let startDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 9, minute: 00, second: 0, of: Date())
        else { fatalError("Date failure 1 !!! (this shouldn't happen)") }
        
        for day in 0..<countOfTimeSlots.count {
            
            guard let thisDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: day, to: startDate)
            else { fatalError("Date failure 2 !!! (this shouldn't happen)") }
            
            var timeSlots: [Date] = []
            
            for n in 0..<countOfTimeSlots[day] {
                
                guard let thisTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: n * 30, to: thisDate)
                else { fatalError("Date failure 3 !!! (this shouldn't happen)") }
                
                timeSlots.append(thisTime)
                
            }
            
            myData.append(EmptySeatStruct(date: thisDate, timeSlots: timeSlots))
            
        }
        
        // for use during development
        //  double-tap anywhere to toggle framing colors
        let dt = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggleFraming(_:)))
        dt.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        view.addGestureRecognizer(dt)

    }
    
    // for use during development
    @objc func toggleFraming(_ sender: Any?) {
        self.showCellFrame.toggle()
        collectionView.backgroundColor = showCellFrame ? .cyan : view.backgroundColor
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        
        coordinator.animate(
            alongsideTransition: { [unowned self] _ in
                self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            },
            completion: { [unowned self] _ in
                // if we want to do something after the size transition
            }
        )
    }
    
}

// "standard" collection view DataSource funcs
extension TimeSlotsViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData[section].timeSlots.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TimeSlotsCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TimeSlotsCell
        
        //c.theImageView.image = myData[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
        // any other cell data configuration
        
        let t = myData[indexPath.section].timeSlots[indexPath.item]
        
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        c.theLabel.text = df.string(from: t)
        
        // this is here only during development
        c.showCellFrame = self.showCellFrame
        
        return c
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: TimeSlotsSectionHeaderView.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TimeSlotsSectionHeaderView
        
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            //headerView.label.text = "Section \(indexPath.section): \(myData[indexPath.section].count) items"
            let df = DateFormatter()
            df.dateFormat = "dd MMMM"
            headerView.labelDate.text = df.string(from: myData[indexPath.section].date)
            df.dateFormat = "cccc"
            headerView.labelWeekday.text = df.string(from: myData[indexPath.section].date)
            headerView.showHeaderFrame = showCellFrame
            
        default:
            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
        }
        
        return headerView
    }
}

// "standard" collection view Delegate funcs
extension TimeSlotsViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected item at:", indexPath)
    }
}

// our custom Layout delegate funcs
extension TimeSlotsViewController: TimeSlotsGridLayoutDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForSectionHeaderAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 64.0
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, insetsForSectionHeaderAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        // let's add a little "padding" above the section header views
        //  0-points for the First one (Section: 0)
        // and 8-points between the bottom of a section
        //  and the top of the next section header
        let t: CGFloat = section == 0 ? 0.0 : 8.0
        return .init(top: t, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    }
    func itemSize(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> CGSize {
        return .init(width: 80.0, height: 80.0)
    }
    func itemSpacing(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> CGFloat {
        // for this example, we'll add 2-points between items (cells)
        return 2.0
    }
    func rowSpacing(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> CGFloat {
        // for this example, we'll add 2-points between "cell rows"
        return 2.0
    }

}
```

Everything is done via code - no `@IBOutlet` connections - just assign `TimeSlotsViewController` as the custom class for a fresh `UIViewController`.

Looks like this when running:

[image]

and scrolling down a bit:

[image]

Double-tap anywhere to toggle "dev-mode coloring" so we can see the framing:

[image]

and, how it looks when the device is rotated:

[image]

[image]

Note: This is ***Example Code Only!!!*** It is not intended to be "production ready." Hopefully you will find it helpful, and can use it as a basis for code that will fit your specific design needs...