# Double height cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

How can I implement such layout using UICollectionView in UIKit? I need to add a new cell which height is greater than height of normal cell. AFAIK all cells in one row of UICollectionView must have the same height.

[image: portrait mode]

[image: landscape mode]

Comment: You can do this with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` ... here is an example of a layout that is *similar* to what you're showing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75902340/6257435 ... it should get you on your way. If you have any questions about it, I'm happy to help you convert that to fit your needs.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this?

Comment: @DonMag sorry. Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/77895065/10879459 helped me to get desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` will fit this scenario. It supports complex collection UI, like waterfall, nested cells, etc. And based on your requirements, it could be:

```swift
//Defining sections
enum Section: Int, Hashable {
    case waterfall
    case normal
}
```

```swift
//And layouts for sections
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
    guard let sectionKind = Section(rawValue: sectionIndex) else { return nil}

    let section: NSCollectionLayoutSection

    if sectionKind == .waterfall {
        let leadingItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.7),
                                               heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)))
        leadingItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)

        let trailingItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                               heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.3)))
        trailingItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
        let trailingGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.3),
                                               heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)),
            subitem: trailingItem, count: 2)

        let nestedGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                               heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.4)),
            subitems: [leadingItem, trailingGroup])
        section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: nestedGroup)

    } else {
        let leadingItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5),
                                               heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)))
        leadingItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)

        let trailingItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5),
                                               heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)))
        trailingItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)

        let nestedGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                               heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.2)),
            subitems: [leadingItem, trailingItem])
        section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: nestedGroup)
    }

    return section
}

collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

The following is an explanation of the layouts above (all with insets):

> `waterfall`: A section that has (width: 1.0, height: 0.4) ratio with collectionView frame. It contains a leading cell item with (width: 0.7, height: 1.0). And a pair of trailing vertical cells with (width: 0.3, height: 1.0). Each cell in this group will have (width: 1.0, height: 0.3) to their group

> `normal`: A section that has (width: 1.0, height 0.2) ratio with collectionView frame. The layout will present two cells and each cell will get 0.5 width of collectionView.

**UPDATED**: I used `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`, configured it is simple:

```swift
//A struct to represent cell data. Notice: it has to conform Hashable
struct CellData: Hashable {
    var title: String = ""
    var identifier: UUID = .init()

    init(_ title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

//A dataSource represents collectionView data
var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, CellData>
```

Then append sections and items like you want:

```
//Simple text cell with a label
let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<TextCell, CellData> { (cell, indexPath, identifier) in
    cell.label.text = identifier.title
    //Other configurations
}

dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, CellData>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: { collectionView, indexPath, item in
    collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: item)
})

var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, CellData>()
snapshot.appendSections([.waterfall])
let dummyWaterfallSection: [CellData] = [
    .init("1"),
    .init("2"),
    .init("3"),
]
snapshot.appendItems(dummyWaterfallSection, toSection: .waterfall)

snapshot.appendSections([.normal])
let dummyNormalSection: [CellData] = [
    .init("11"),
    .init("22"),
    .init("33"),
    .init("44"),
    .init("55"),
]
snapshot.appendItems(dummyNormalSection, toSection: .normal)

dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the data setup code that produces the OP's desired layout(s)?

Comment: Aw, right, I forgot it, will update the answer thanks @DonMag

Comment: Does that produce the second 2-column layout, or any of the 3-column layouts, the OP is going for?

Comment: I've made a piece of code to represent what CompositionalLayOut can do. Actually I didn't cover all cases on the example above. However, I think its possible even 2-3 columns.

Comment: I.e, the layout which has the biggest cell at the center, could be designed with three horizontal groups. I think its more powerful than the old school style collection flow layout. But the suggestion on your comment is still great.

Comment: I imagine it *could* be done with `CompositionalLayout` ... but I suspect it will be more difficult than using a custom layout.

Answer (score -1):

you can set that specific cell size in the below way:

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.item == /*your desired cell index*/ {
            return CGSize(width: normalWidth, height: doubleSizeHeight)            
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: normalWidth, height: normalHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `/*your desired cell index*/` is `0`, this is the result:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aladK.png ... which is not the OP's goal.